# Trabalhando com array de checkbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Bem, é o seguinte, estou querendo editar um registro que contêm somente um nome e um array de outros registros, ifs (um relacionamento 1 para N). Esse array de ifs eu jogo na view como checkboxs, mas não estou conseguindo fazer com que ele fique checado.

Estou usando vuejs. Eu queria que, quando eu clicasse em editar, deixasse já checado os estados que ele jã tem.

[image: lista de registros]

[image: edição de registro]

Comment: Essa caixa "Atualizar" é um modal?

Comment: Sim. Mas pode ser outra página sem problemas.

Comment: E esse campo "Nome de pesquisa", é dinâmico? Tipo ao digitar abre outros nomes?

Comment: Não. É somente isso. Perceba que, na primeira imagem, o nome de pesquisa "JOSIVAN SOUSA" tem vários estados relacionados a ele. Eu quero deixar os estados relacionados a ele checado na segunda imagem

Comment: Entendi. Posta o HTML de um desses botões "editar" pra gente vê o que tem nele e saber o que fazer.

Comment: Creio ser possível fazer isso usando apenas JavaScript: ao abrir o modal, eu chamo uma função que irá buscar os estados dentro da linha da tabela e comparar com os checkboxes. Os estados que tiverem na linha, eu marco o checkbox correspondente na modal.

Comment: Quando eu clico em editar, eu pego pego os seguintes dados:                 
 `{
  "idnomes": 15,
  "strnome": "JOSIVAN SOUSA",
  "has_uf": [
    {
      "iduf": 1,
      "struf": "AC",
      "strdescricao": "Acre",
      "bolvisualizar": 1
    },
    {
      "iduf": 2,
      "struf": "PA",
      "strdescricao": "Para",
      "bolvisualizar": 1
    },
    {
      "iduf": 2,
      "struf": "MA",
      "strdescricao": "Maranhão",
      "bolvisualizar": 1
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: Só que estou com dificuldades para deixar os checkboxs checado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você clica em "Editar", você pega um código em formato JSON:

```
{ "idnomes": 15, "strnome": "JOSIVAN SOUSA", "has_uf": [ { "iduf": 1, "struf": "AC", "strdescricao": "Acre", "bolvisualizar": 1 }, { "iduf": 2, "struf": "PA", "strdescricao": "Para", "bolvisualizar": 1 }, { "iduf": 2, "struf": "MA", "strdescricao": "Maranhão", "bolvisualizar": 1 } ] }
```

Precisa agora fazer um `parse` nesse código transformando-o em um objeto JSON:

```
objeto = JSON.parse('{ "idnomes": 15, "strnome": "JOSIVAN SOUSA", "has_uf": [ { "iduf": 1, "struf": "AC", "strdescricao": "Acre", "bolvisualizar": 1 }, { "iduf": 2, "struf": "PA", "strdescricao": "Para", "bolvisualizar": 1 }, { "iduf": 2, "struf": "MA", "strdescricao": "Maranhão", "bolvisualizar": 1 } ] }');
```

Depois pegar todos os `checkbox` que tem no modal (altere "meumodal" para o `id` do seu modal):

```
elems = document.getElementById("meumodal").getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Em seguida um *loop* duplo irá checar os `checkbox` que tiverem `value` igual à sigla no JSON:

```
for(x=0;x<objeto.has_uf.length;x++){
    for(y=0;y<elems.length;y++){
        if(elems[y].value == objeto.has_uf[x].struf){
            elems[y].checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Abra o exemplo abaixo:**

```js
objeto = JSON.parse('{ "idnomes": 15, "strnome": "JOSIVAN SOUSA", "has_uf": [ { "iduf": 1, "struf": "AC", "strdescricao": "Acre", "bolvisualizar": 1 }, { "iduf": 2, "struf": "PA", "strdescricao": "Para", "bolvisualizar": 1 }, { "iduf": 2, "struf": "MA", "strdescricao": "Maranhão", "bolvisualizar": 1 } ] }');
elems = document.getElementById("meumodal").getElementsByTagName("input");
for(x=0;x<objeto.has_uf.length;x++){
 for(y=0;y<elems.length;y++){
  if(elems[y].value == objeto.has_uf[x].struf){
   elems[y].checked = true;
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="meumodal">
 <input type="checkbox" value="AC" /> AC
    <br />
 <input type="checkbox" value="DF" /> DF
    <br />
 <input type="checkbox" value="MA" /> AC
</div>
```